# showing instructions for command line inputs in a bash script when run without inputs or wrong inputs

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have created a bash script which takes 2 command line arguments. It works absolutely fine.
I want to go a step further, and want to show the types of arguments it takes. i.e. if we run **my_script.bash --help** it should tell the desired arguments in its order.

**my_script.bash** is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

X="$1" ## Name
Y="$2" ## address

 echo " Mr./Ms. $X lives in $Y ."
```

Since it takes two arguments name and address, I want to show these when this bash is executed without any inputs or number of inputs or using **my_script.bash --help** command.

ie executing **./my_script.bash** or **./my_script.bash --help** should show like below

```
$  ./my_script.bash

>>this script takes two arguments. please enter **Name** and **address**
```

Since these arguments are position specific so we cannot change the positions of Name and Address. It would be great if we could pass the arguments by defining --name --address.

```
$  ./my_script.bash --address Delhi --name Gupta
 >>  Mr./Ms. Gupta lives in Delhi .
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're asking a bunch of questions here. Could you please clarify one?

Comment: I have asked only one question which is to show the help when either asked or passes wrong arguments.

Answer (score 2):

A basic option parsing loop uses `while` and `case`, and looks like this:

```
print_help ()
{
    cat <<-EOF
    ${0##*/} - process name and address

    --name NAME        your name
    --address ADDRESS  your address
    --help             this help
    EOF
}

die ()
{
    echo "$@" >&2
    exit 1
}

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
        --help)
            print_help
            exit
        ;;
        --name)
            shift || die "$1: requires input"
            name=$1
        ;;
        --address)
            shift || die "$1: requires input"
            address=$1
        ;;
        *)
            die "$1: invalid argument"
    esac
    shift
done
```

The order of options doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi @dan Thanks for your kind consideration. Since I am new to bash scripting and want to learn as much as possible. It is hard for me to understand the syntax of the above code. Could you please give me some reference to this particular query.

Comment: `print_help` and `die` are functions. `die` prints an error and exits. The `while` loop iterates each argument and parses it using `case`, assigning the name and address variables, also checking for invalid input. `$#` is the number of positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc). `shift` shifts these such that `$2` becomes `$1` and `$3` becomes `$2`, etc, reducing `$#`. The loop breaks when `$#` is zero.

Comment: @shivam You can copy paste this code and use it in your script. If given as arguments, as in your example,`$name` and `$address` will be available after the loop. I recommend `man bash` for further reading. Specifically, search for keywords like `while`, `[[`, `case`, and `shift`, also functions, here-documents, and positional parameters. This loop is a standard way to parse options. There is also the builtin `getopts` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for `[[ $1 == --help ]]`, but since your script has 2 required arguments, you could simply print the help whenever the number of arguments is not equal 2:

```
if (( $# != 2 ))
then
  echo You have to provide 2 arguments 1>&2
  exit 1
fi
```